# upload date with webservce in sql server

Tags: java, android, web-services, datetime

am using a webservice implemented in c# in order to upload some values in sql server. the code that am usgin is in java android.
my problem is that it accept only the date (yyyy-MM-dd) but i have to save the datetime.
am usiging this code

```
String currentDateTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
        request.addProperty("DateTimeStamp",currentDateTimeString);
```

i try all formats for time that i can find but it does not accept anything.

the same webservice is been using from a c# application and is working just fine. it use
`private DateTime timeStamp;`

what it could be the equivalent in java android.?
sql server is 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    values.put("time", dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: unfortunetly still not working. from the web service the response is null, if i add only the date without the time it just working fine. any other ideas that could help?